# Handling large size of Read operation

Tags: c, libc

I am interposing a read operation with my own implementation of `read` that prints some log and calls the libc `read`. I am wondering what should be the right way to handle `read` with a huge `nbyte` parameter. Since `nbyte` is `size_t`, what is the right way to handle out of range read request? From the `read` manpage:

> If the value of nbyte is greater than {SSIZE_MAX}, the result is implementation-defined

What does this mean and if I have to handle a large read request, what should I do?

Comment: I think the problem will be more the ram than the SSIZE_MAX. but you can cut it in smaller reads.

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard *you can cut it in smaller reads*  Then how do you pass the total bytes read back to the caller?  The total is greater than `SSIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle if the function is well done, it will also return the number of bytes read, so if it return SSIZE_MAX, it mean that there is still bytes to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change the behavior of the `read()` call - just wrap the OS-provided call and allow it to do what it does.

```
ssize_t read( int fd, void *buf, size_t bytes )
{
    ssize_t result;
        .
        .
        .
    result = read_read( fd, buf, bytes );
       .
       .
       .
    return( result );
}
```

What could you possibly do if you're implementing a 64-bit library a caller passes you a `size_t` value that's greater than `SSIZE_MAX`?  You can't split that up into anything reasonable anyway.

And if you're implementing a 32-bit library, how would you pass the proper result back if you did split up the read?

Answer (score 2):

You could break up the one large request into several smaller ones.

Besides, `SSIZE_MAX` is positively huge. Are you really sure you need to read >2GB of data, in one go?

Comment: And if you did break up the `read()` call into smaller ones, how would you then pass the total number of bytes read back to the caller?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: There are various ways. A `size_t *` out parameter. A `size_t` return value and an *error code* out parameter, or a wrapping object akin to `FILE *` that carries an error flag. There are more, but those are even more questionable than the bad joke that is `ssize_t`. (The architect in me cringes whenever I see that particular "thing"...)

Comment: *There are various ways.*  No there aren't.  OP is interposing on `ssize_t read( int fd, void *buf, size_t bytes )`.  That means he's providing his own implementation of the standard `read()` call.  All he can do is return one `ssize_t` result indicating the total number of bytes read.  If the input `size_t bytes` parameter is greater than `SSIZE_MAX`, there's no way to sum up separate `read()` calls and then pass the results indicating the total number of bytes read back in a way that would fit properly into the `ssize_t` return value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Your comment is based on the assumption that the OP *has* to mimic the exact parameter list and return type of `read()`. In that case you would be correct. My comments are based on the assumption that the OP has control over both ends of the call, i.e. could use a modified parameter list / return code for his reads. The second line of my answer is where it's actually at, though: The necessity for monolithic reads of more than `SSIZE_MAX` bytes should be rare.

Comment: OP stated that he's *interposing a read operation with my own implementation of `read`*.  "Interposing" means he's loading his own shared library before `libc` and replacing the standard `read()` call from `libc` with his own and therefore duplicate the syntax and semantics of the standard `read()` call.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Yes, that's what interposing *can* mean. I don't even know if the OP is a native speaker. I know that *I* am not a native speaker. And so I am willing to give things the benefit of a doubt. Besides, since `read()` explicitly leaves values > `SSIZE_MAX` to "implementation defined", OP could just define it differently for *his* implementation, can't he? Now, can you *please* get off my back about how your reading of the question differs from mine?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to get some logs of your `read` syscalls.

In practice the read count is the size of some buffer (in memory), so it is very unusual to have it being bigger than a dozen of megabytes. It is often some kilobytes.

So I believe you should not care about `SSIZE_MAX` limit in real life

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter of read is the buffer size. It's not the number of bytes to read.

So:

- if the buffer size you received is lesser than SSIZE_MAX, call the syscall 'read' with buffer size.
- If the buffer size you received is greater than SSIZE_MAX, 'read' SSIZE_MAX
- If the read syscall return -1, return -1 too
- If the read syscall return 0 or less than SSIZE_MAX --> return the sum of bytes read.
- If the read call return exactly SSIZE_MAX, decrement the buffer size received of SSIZE_MAX
- and loop (goto "So")

Do not forget to adjust the buffer pointer and to count the total number of bytes read.

Answer (score 1):

Being implementation defined means that there is no correct answer, and callers should never do this (because they can’t be certain how it will be handled).  Given that you are interposing the syscall, I suggest you just assert(2) that the value is in range.  If you end up failing that assert somewhere, fix the calling code to be compliant.